# SQLAlchemy 0.7 MapperEvent error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have model

```
class CreatedMixin(object):

    __abstract__ = True

    @declared_attr
    def created_by(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.user_id',
                      onupdate="cascade", ondelete="restrict"))

    @declared_attr
    def updated_by(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.user_id',
                      onupdate="cascade", ondelete="restrict"))

    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.now(),
                        onupdate=dt.now())


class Net(Base, CreatedMixin):
    """Net or subnet."""

    cidr = Column(postgresql.CIDR, index = True)
    description = Column(UnicodeText())

    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('net.id'))
    parent = relationship("Net", remote_side="Net.id")

   def __init__(self, cidr=''):
       self.cidr = cidr

   def __repr__(self):
       return "%s" % self.cidr
```

To autofill fields created_by and update_by I use `sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents` (SQLAlchemy 0.7) like this:

```
def created_before_insert_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    # execute a stored procedure upon INSERT,
    # apply the value to the row to be inserted
    #target.calculated_value = connection.scalar(
    #                            "select my_special_function(%d)" 
    #                            % target.special_number)
    target.updated_by = 1

# associate the listener function with CreatedMixin,
# to execute during the "before_insert" hook
event.listen(CreatedMixin, 'before_insert', created_before_insert_listener)
```

But after run app, got the following error but is not mapped

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class 'myapp.model.Net'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The information you provided is not enough to find the source of error. Please post traceback here. Is `Base` class created properly? Is module `myapp.model` imported before code causing error is executed?

Comment: trace: http://pylonshq.com/tracebacks/090785ad315b0acb6a20b849dd049864

Comment: I noticed that the models no longer be determined after the upgrade to 0.7 version. When I initialization database through paster setup-app on 0.6 version work fine, but 0.7 doesn't create table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was quite simple, I use an Mixin in my models and inadvertently added to the basic model of property `__abstract__ = True`

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine))

class Mix(object):
    __abstract__ = True
    id =  Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)

class User(Base, Mix):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

Base.metadata.create_all()

u = User()
print u
```

But in SQLAlchemy 0.6 it works fine. Perhaps this is a bug of 0.6.
Update: for more information [SQLAlchemy abstract](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html#abstract)